# "NoClassDefFoundError" when running MuleServer from Java after 3.5.0 upgrade

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, testing, mule

I just updated my projects Mule dependencies from 3.3.0 to 3.5.0 in Maven.  This code worked in 3.3.0, but now I'm getting an error.

I am attempting to run the MuleServer Java wrapper from a test class.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mule.MuleServer;
import org.mule.util.ClassUtils;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.mule.tck.junit4.AbstractMuleTestCase;

public class RunMuleTest extends AbstractMuleTestCase
{
    @Test
    public void testMuleServer() throws Exception
    {
        MuleServer muleServer = new MuleServer(); // defaults to use "mule-config.xml"
        muleServer.run(false, false);
    }
}
```

I'm using the following Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-client-ee</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0-bighorn</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<!-- plus a few others like spring, json, etc-->
```

I also have my "mule-config.xml" under "src/main/app".

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mule/api/config/DomainMuleContextAwareConfigurationBuilder
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils$7.run(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils$7.run(ClassUtils.java:244)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:243)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:212)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.isClassOnPath(ClassUtils.java:690)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:84)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:47)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:73)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.MuleServer.initialize(MuleServer.java:383)
    at com.teracyte.mule.test.RunMuleTest.testMuleServer(RunMuleTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.api.config.DomainMuleContextAwareConfigurationBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 28 more
```

It's not clear what's missing to make this run again.

Any ideas what needs to be modified to make this work again?

Comment: You are using EE artifacts: do you have access to MuleSoft's EE Maven repo?

Comment: Yes.  It is mirrored in my Maven Nexus proxy.

Comment: Then best is to contact MuleSoft support, since you're an EE subscriber.